# Google Maps polygon comprised of circles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a weird bug where all polygons I draw are made up of circles. When I zoom in or out the diameter and number of circles changes. Anyone else had this problem? Google Maps V3, JS. Tried Chrome and Firesfox - same thing.

```
//draw polygon
    geoFenceGeometry = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: geoFencePoints,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 4,
        editable:true,
        draggable:true,
        geodesic:true,
        fillColor: "#000000",
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
    });
    geoFenceGeometry.addListener("mouseup", () => {
        
        geoFencePoints = geoFenceGeometry.getPath();
        if(geoFencePoints.length >= geoFencePointsMaxLen) geoFenceGeometry.setOptions({editable:false});
        redrawPolygonMarkers();
        
    });
    geoFenceGeometry.setMap(map);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is caused by interferrence with other styles on the website. This bug was fixed by adding following CSS to map canvas style:

```
#map {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-radius:0;
}
#map * {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border-radius:0; 
}
```